# Is there a way to change the default color of a selected html listbox item?

Tags: html, css, colors, listbox, listboxitem

Ok, not sure if this is even possible, but I want to change the default color of a selected HTML listbox item. I'm not talking about the background color of the listbox option tag. That can be done through CSS, I get that. I'm talking about the color that overrides that background color when the item is selected. In Chrome, FF, and IE if I just change the background color to red and then select the item from the list, the color is now blue. I can't seem to find anything on whether or not overriding the color is possible, but I was hoping someone here might know. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Although I've never encountered this on any site, and I don't think it is possible because there is no real "item" object for a listbox in javascript (not that I know of), it's a good question.

Comment: Sorry, but by "item" I mean <option> tag

Comment: OP....If you want to style the select box use my solution below.  Just because people think it is not best practice to style select box doesn't mean you shouldn't use it.  Look into the jQuery chosen and it works across all platforms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not reliably. The `<select>` element's rendering is controlled by the operating system, so it's not something that's simple to style. Most services that attempt this use JS/HTML/CSS to create pseudo- elements that can be styled at will rather than true `<select>`s.

Generally speaking, I wouldn't recommend styling this element for UX reasons anyway. Users need to see UI elements acting and looking in similar ways to grok their purpose and behaviour. Overriding default behaviour can erode that.

Comment: The OP is asking about styling the select box not whether or not it is generally accepted to by UX design.

Comment: @Chad - jimmy wasn't talking about the design. the (valid) argument is that the User's eXperience may be compromised due to their expectations from the operating system's UI. he also went the extra mile by contributing with the added value of an educated advice.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy. This was the conclusion I had come to myself. I just wanted to throw this question out there and see if anyone else could confim this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

When I style select boxes I use jQuery chosen and edit the CSS

http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Comment: i mean the infamous 'golden-hammer' anti-pattern: if all you have is a hammer, everything start to look like a nail. jQuery is not meant to solve everything.

Comment: jQuery is a great framework and you can style the select box using jQuery chosen, which is exactly what the OP wanted to do, and it works across all browsers.  To my knowledge this is the only solution.  Just because you dont want to use jQuery doesn't mean the person posting the question does not.  And your rationality on every answer being jquery shows your ignorance and you probably need to stop trolling this website with stupid comments like you just left.  If jQuery makes things easier, then use it.

Comment: i meant no harm, and sorry if you were offended by it. just expressing my thoughts on the subject. regardless, i don't appreciate your language, this is no place for this kind of comments.

Comment: BTW jQuery don't style the selectbox per-seh, it just replaces it with a style-able structure, i.e. unordered list.

Comment: I use jQuery all the time. That plugin is a very nice plugin and I will probably use it for a future project, but the original intent of my post was to try and change the browsers default selected color without re-skinning the listbox.

Comment: Most jQuery plugins just hide your original list and replace it with a new styled "list" that is actually a bunch of <div> tags.

Comment: Yes it does not actually change the original but it allows you to change the style of what appears to be the style box.  The reason for this is because you are unable to actually change the style of the browsers select box in most cases